# How to prevent OS X's 'screen' command from resizing the terminal upon entry?

Tags: terminal, screen, iterm, display

I usually run my terminal sessions in 132 character wide mode in iTerm.  However, when I start the 'screen' command, it re-sizes the terminal back to 80 characters.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: use `tmux` instead, basically they have same functions, just tmux is more environment-friendly

Comment: good suggestion, however getting tmux setup in other environments may not be doable in certain situations.

Comment: search for info on configuring your ~/[.screenrc](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Startup-Files.html) file to do what you need.